# Undefined property: ModelTask::$useDbConfig

Tags: cakephp

in CakePHP book example [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/642/Preparing-our-Application)
I try:
cake bake all
then I choose 1 for Group

but i get an error

> Notice: Undefined property: ModelTask::$useDbConfig in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/acl_cake/cake/console/libs/tasks/model.php on line
> 848
>
> Fatal error: ConnectionManager::getDataSource - Non-existent data
> source  in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/acl_cake/cake/libs/model/connection_manager.php on
> line 109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem temporarily by adding

```
$this->useDbConfig = 'default';
```

at line 848 of the file cake/console/libs/tasks/model.php
before the instruction

```
$data = $schema->read(array('models' => false, 'connection' => $this->useDbConfig));
```

And now the bake all is working.